# How do i validate email and mobile number using zend framework addValidator?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

is there any way to use **zend 1** validation to validate if **mobile or email** address using **single one** filed, i have tried to use the below code but it not work ?

```
 ->setRequired(true)

 ->addValidators(
       array(
          array("Digits", true),
          array("EmailAddress",true)
            )
   )
```

Comment: `filter_var($email, filter_validate_email);` http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp

Comment: @ Refilon  how can i use filter_validate_email with zend form addValidators ?

Comment: create a custom validator

Comment: thanx i have used this code 
  `if (filter_var($valueTrim, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           return $valueTrim;
        }elseif(preg_match("/^([ 0-9+]+)$/", $valueTrim) && strlen("$valueTrim") > 8){
            return $valueTrim;
        }else{
            false;
        }`